# How to check input validation equals "0" and only "0"?

Tags: jquery

Need help with this part of a jQuery validation check:

```
  if ($(this).val() == badTumblrInput && $(this).val() != "0")
```

I need to allow only the single character zero ("0") to be valid in the expression.

This code allows anything with a zero ("0") to be valid.

Thanks from a newbie!

Comment: If you want to allow only the single character zero ("0") to be valid in the expression, so why are you using `!= "0"`?

Answer (score 4):

```
if (this.value == '0') {
    //the value was zero, the character zero, and only the character zero
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z4kBM/1/)

Comment: Isn't `this.value` always a string?

Comment: -1 The property `this.value` will return a string, e.g. `"0"`, which is not the same as the number `0`. You could use the `==` operator to make the comparison for `"0"` be true, but that would also allow for example `"00000000000000000000000000000000"` in the input.

Comment: You should use `$(this).val()` as in the post.. we don't know if it just `<input type="text"` or `<select..`

Comment: @Rocket yes, even if explicitly set as an integer.

Comment: @Rocket - you are of course right, it's always a string and needs to be parsed to match numbers.

Comment: The input is a text value. That's what I meant by zero is the character "0".

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using != if you want it to be equal.  But to answer your question you should use `!==` or `===` depending on what you are trying to do.

These are exact comparison operators that take type (string, integer, etc.) into consideration.
For example:

```
('0' == 0) // true
(false == 0) // true
('0' === 0) // false
(false === 0) // false
('0' != 0) // false
(false != 0) // false
('0' !== 0) // true
(false !== 0) // true
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I want the result in your first example but != which is the opposite (which I'm using).